# Subscribe to an Observable without triggering it and then passing it on

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

This could get a little bit complicated and I'm not that experienced with Observables and the RX pattern so bear with me:

Suppose you've got some arbitrary SDK method which returns an Observable. You consume the method from a class which is - among other things - responsible for retrieving data and, while doing so, does some caching, so let's call it `DataProvider`. Then you've got another class which wants to access the data provided by `DataProvider`. Let's call it `Consumer` for now. So there we've got our setup.

Side note for all the pattern friends out there: I'm aware that this is not MVP, it's just an example for an analogous, but much more complex problem I'm facing in my application.

That being said, in Kotlin-like pseudo code the described situation would look like this:

```
class Consumer(val provider: DataProvider) {
    fun logic() {
         provider.getData().subscribe(...)
    }
}

class DataProvider(val sdk: SDK) {
    fun getData(): Consumer {
         val observable = sdk.getData()
         observable.subscribe(/*cache data as it passes through*/)
         return observable
    }
}

class SDK {
    fun getData(): Observable {
         return fetchDataFromNetwork()
    }
}
```

The problem is, that upon calling `sdk.subscribe()` in the `DataProvider` I'm already triggering the Observable's `subscribe()` method which I don't want. I want the `DataProvider` to just silently listen - in this example the triggering should be done by the `Consumer`.

So what's the best RX compatible solution for this problem? The one outlined in the pseudo code above definitely isn't for various reasons one of which is the premature triggering of the network request before the `Consumer` has subscribed to the Observable. I've experimented with `publish().autoComplete(2)` before calling `subscribe()` in the `DataProvider`, but that doesn't seem to be the canonical way to do this kind of things. It just feels hacky.

**Edit**: Through SO's excellent "related" feature I've just stumbled across another question pointing in a different direction, but having a solution which could also be applicable here namely `flatMap()`. I knew that one before, but never actually had to use it. Seems like a viable way to me - what's your opinion regarding that?

Comment: There must be a way to get away without calling `subscribe()` inside `DataProvider#getData()`, but rather using other operators depending on what you need: `doOnNext()` if you need to do some side actions without modifying events in the chain, `map` or `flatMap` if you need to transform them on their way, etc.

Comment: I wasn't aware of  `doOnNext()` - will try it out now.

Comment: @AndroidEx `doOnNext()` worked out great! Please convert your comment to an answer and I'll gladly mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: posted the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the caching step is not supposed to modify events in the chain, the `doOnNext()` operator can be used:

```
class DataProvider(val sdk: SDK) {
    fun getData(): Observable<*> = sdk.getData().doOnNext(/*cache data as it passes through*/)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `flatMap` could be a solution. Moreover you could split your stream into chain of small `Observables`:

```
public class DataProvider {

    private Api api;
    private Parser parser;
    private Cache cache;

    public Observable<List<User>> getUsers() {
        return api.getUsersFromNetwork()
                .flatMap(parser::parseUsers)
                .map(cache::cacheUsers);
    }
}

public class Api {
    public Observable<Response> getUsersFromNetwork() {
        //makes https request or whatever
    }
}

public class Parser {
    public Observable<List<User>> parseUsers(Response response) {
        //parse users
    }
}

public class Cache {
    public List<User> cacheUsers(List<User> users) {
        //cache users
    }
}
```

It's easy to test, maintain and replace implementations(with usage of interfaces). Also you could easily insert additional step into your stream(for instance log/convert/change data which you receive from server).

The other quite convenient operator is `map`. Basically instead of `Observable<Data>` it returns just `Data`. It could make your code even simpler.

Comment: I used @AndroidEx's solution in the end. However your solution also sounds viable. Therefore I'll upvote it, too. Thanks!